# Can you transfer iPhone backups made on Windows to a Mac?

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup

I made an iPhone backup on someone else windows computer and now need to send it to my Mac to restore my iPhone because it got bricked. If I simply send the file over a torrent and put it in the backup folder on my Mac's iTunes, will I have any trouble with restoring my device? I'm worried the format that iTunes on windows uses is different then on Macs'.

follow up question: Is there a better way then a torrent to send a file about 50gb?

Comment: You can mount samba shares on a Mac, send them via SCP, or use a USB stick. Torrenting is a terrible idea for sharing a file with 1 user.

Answer (score 4):

The backup format is the same for Mac and Windows, so you can copy your backup from the `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup` folder on your Windows computer to `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup` on your Mac yes. [If you need instructions for various versions of Mac and Windows to access these folders, here's a blog post I wrote with them.](https://deciphertools.com/blog/where-are-iphone-backups/)

If you have a USB thumb drive, that may be better to copy the 50GB backup. :) You could also right-click on the folder for the backup and select Send To > Compressed Folder first to zip it.

Answer (score 0):

`BitTorrent` is actually quite well suited to transferring very large files or groups of files. It can be a good choice, especially if the user is already familiar with it.

The BitTorrent protocol:

1. is *(relatively?)* efficient
2. tolerates errors well and can recover from interrupted transfers
3. doesn’t have some of the inefficiencies / overhead of the SMB3 protocol used by modern file sharing on macOS and Windows, *especially* if you’re transferring a folder containing many *(i.e. hundreds or thousands)* of separate files.

Notes:

1. Just transfer over the actual ‘.torrent’ file,
   a. or use a magnet link in clients with ‘local peer discovery enabled.
2. For private files, just don’t publish the ‘.torrent’ file to any trackers.

If you aren’t familiar with `BitTorrent`, [Resilio Sync](https://www.resilio.com/individuals/) uses the same technology but without the ‘scary’ BitTorrent name. It works much like Dropbox _(but without any data stored in ‘the cloud’) and is just as easy to set up. Free for home use.

If you were to make the iOS backup directly into a folder shared by *Resilio Sync* on both computers, you might actually find that most of the data is already synchronized *before the backup is even complete*!

---

Regardless of the program one uses, depending on network speed, a local network transfer is very likely to be faster than even a good quality USB 3 ‘thumb drive’.